# Why do log files show only the first letter of a word?

Tags: plain-tex, logging

If I create `hello.tex` thus:

```
\tracingcommands 1
Hello world
```

then hello.log contains

```
This is TeX, [etc]
**hello.tex
(./hello.tex
{vertical mode: the letter H}
{horizontal mode: the letter H}
{blank space  }
{the letter w}
{blank space  }
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> hello.tex
             
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pages of output.
```

Fine, but what about the letters e, l, l, o and o, r, l, d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"why" answers are hard to answer, it's just the way the designer chose to log things, but essentially it is logging the start of possible hyphenation points.

Notable here is that the timing of the hyphenation pass in luatex is different and luatex reports

```
{vertical mode: the letter H}
{horizontal mode: the letter H}
{the letter e}
{the letter l}
{the letter l}
{the letter o}
{blank space  }
{the letter w}
{the letter o}
{the letter r}
{the letter l}
{the letter d}
{blank space  }
{\par}
```

Comment: Well, then ``plain-tex'' should show the hyphen in the trace; TeX
traces words of letters and characters as one unit. And it's more
important that a mode change is possible as shown in the first two
lines of the luatex trace. (It probably has also to do with efficiency
as the main_loop must not return to the big_switch for every character
and ligature handling is easier and faster.)

Comment: @UdoWermuth er yes "start of hyphenation" was sort of a deliberate white lie, as (as you say) it's more a case of start of "something in a different part of the implementation" I didn't want to get in to. I don't think simply saying "TeX traces words of letters and characters as one unit." helps, it is true of course but essentially the OP's question is asking why does it do that.

Comment: I understand why you said that my wording doesn't help to answer the question. ``Why'' questions are difficult to answer. With enough whys you get to box-glue-penalty and then there might come another why. That's why I didn't try to write an own answer to this question.